# Is this question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question struck me as very unusual when compared to our other questions:

[Does handling a lot of flour cause fingernails to break?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/68323/1672) (unedited title was simply "Bread baking fanatic")

What does the community think? Should such a question be on-topic or not? Why, or why not?

Comment: I am in favour of closing the question; I am not sure what kind of useful answer the community could provide, and it may be that the OP has an underlying undiagnosed medical problem completely unrelated to baking.

Comment: For comparison: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21469/1672.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod I think you're almost assuming an answer there: if this were a normal thing that  commonly happens, then you wouldn't speculate about underlying conditions, and people would be able to answer. If not... then that's the answer; we don't need to diagnose the OP's actual issue.

Comment: This discussion is helpful, especially for people like me.  I only recently earned late answer and first post review privileges here, but haven't used them much because I'm still trying to learn by reading what the experienced reviewers are doing. I'm probably not qualified to add an opinion here, but I look forward to seeing what happens!

Comment: At first I believed  the question should be closed, but after thinking about it, is it really that different from "cutting onions make me cry"? I really don't like the wording in the question, but now think it's okay.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say yes, though it could probably use editing (hint hint): it's about something potentially happening because of the actual cooking, not just a health question about *eating* food, and it's a relatively acute problem, not a long-term fuzzy health issue.

It seems roughly in the same category as onions making us cry (thanks, Debbie!) or [butternut squash messing with our skin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21469/1672). I actually like the butternut squash comparison here, because the OP definitely seemed unsure if it was at all a normal reaction, so just confirming that it is was helpful. I suspect that in this case the answer might be "no, that's not really a normal thing; if it's bad, go see your doctor" but it still seems fair to ask whether it's a potentially expected issue.

Comment: Okay I got two upvotes and no comments with an unfinished sentence in the first paragraph... y'all are reading what I post, right? :)

Comment: I still don't know the future of the question, but I took a shot at editing. I'll wait to see if it's helpful. :)